# Cleartext http traffic to server.com not permitted

Tags: android, android-volley

My code is working on android KitKat but it when running it in Pie gives io exception

> Cleartext http traffic to server.com not permitted

I'm using volley to make  server calls.

Comment: probably it complains about you using non HTTPS connection.

Comment: so what should i do ,i can't get any response from server as io exception is being caught

Comment: try using HTTPS connection to the server

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android 8: Cleartext HTTP traffic not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First step is understanding *why* Google enforces you to use HTTPS. You can read more about it on the developers page.

As for how to fix it, there are two options:

1) Use HTTPS!

2) Create a new file in your XML folder named `security_config.xml` and add this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

then in your Manifest file add this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ... >
    <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/security_config">

    </application>
</manifest>
```

For obvious reasons, the second point is not recommended!

Comment: what is the exact link you're trying to connect to?

Comment: after that it gives  exception also on kitkat

Comment: instead of adding trust anchors, you can simply add a domain  with subdomain true, which is correct way .so it will allow only that particular website instead of whole system.

Answer (score 9):

Simple Solution:

Add this line in your manifest:

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

because I have faced the same issue with my php page for json api.

It should look like this:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        ...
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        ...>
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Let's hope it works.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have the option of using HTTPS, then you can use a network security configuration xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <network-security-config>
        <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
            <domain includeSubdomains="true">192.168.1.100</domain>
            <domain includeSubdomains="true">http://example1.com</domain>
            <domain includeSubdomains="true">example1.com</domain>
        </domain-config>
    </network-security-config>
```

Then you need to add it to your `<application` section in the Android Manifest with this line

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/testing_security"
```

Some alternatives were presented in other answers - i would say that allowing all cleartext traffic is unwise since 3rd party libraries could compromise you. It is best to explicitly define your host targets to minimise the impact of this insecure communication

Comment: Controlling the specific set of domains makes a lot of sense. This is my preferred answer.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the android:usesCleartextTraffic attribute in the application element of your AndroidManifest.xml works!

To do this in **Xamarin Forms** you can achieve this by adding the following in the **AssemblyInfo.cs** of your Android solution.

```
// Because I only want this in development
#if DEBUG 
[assembly: Application(UsesCleartextTraffic = true)]
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solved**

**Edit your** ► ’ network security_config.xml ’

**Add line** ► Domain.com OR your IP(12.34.456.78)

after change it will look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
           <domain includeSubdomains="true">Domain.com OR your IP(12.34.456.78)</domain>
           <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```