# Stuck in a white screen after Flutter app is pubblished on Play store

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I have a problem with my release into play store.
On Emulator it works great
when I pubblished it to internal test on Play store and when I run APP it return white screen without any behavior.

This is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}
```

and the gradle version:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2'
```

on emulator it works, if I install APK to my phisical device it works but with once I pubblished in Ply store it stuck on white screen

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Comment: at the end the problem was in the indentation of Gradle file. the solution given by you doesnt solve it but helps.

Comment: Great! Happy to hear that.

Comment: I have the same issue for my app and searching solution. As i think, the only difference for the app from google play is signing certificate. Does anyone have an answer for this question?

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely because 'Cleartext HTTP traffic is not permitted'.  It's stuck on the white screen because it's trying to communicate with your servers\backend, but http traffic isn't allowed by default.

Connect the app you downloaded from the appstore to your computer. Run `adb catlog` and filter your app's package name, and observe the output.

Take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52968315/cleartext-http-traffic-to-server-com-not-permitted), and check it this applies to you. Aside from that, adding  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` to your `AndroidManifest.xml`. And update on the results of these steps, these to two things are your most likely causes of the problem.